# Home work of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$h(x)\in C^2(R^n)$, and $\omega_n$ is the area of unit sphere.Let:
$$
M_h(x,r)=\frac{1}{\omega_nr^{n-1}}\int_{|y-x|=r}h(y)dS_y
$$
proof:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2M_h}{\partial r^2}+\frac{n-1}{r}\frac{\partial M_h}{\partial r}=\Delta_xM_h \\
M_h(x,0)=h(x)\\
\frac{\partial M_h}{\partial r}|_{r=0}=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
$\Delta_x$ is Laplace operator about $x$.

At beginning, I think the question is just a calculation.But I still can't get the answer.

I am really sorry about my off-topic.Because my poor English, I can't accurately describe my question.If there is any missing details, please ask me ,so thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: @5xum  How should I edit my question? I have provided additional context.